# How to disable specific user in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I need to be able to disable a specific user in ServiceStack and I would like to know if this method is a correct one.

```
public class UserManagementService : Service
{
    public void Put(DisableUser request)
    {
        var userAuth = UserAuthRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(request.UserName);
        userAuth.LockedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UserAuthRepo.SaveUserAuth(userAuth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Demis changed the default authentication behaviour to not allow locked users to login since [this](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/03b4778e399c8a0382c151f6fe805367cd32ff86) commit.